# Can we build base docker images which are GUI enabled (NO X11 forwarding)?

Tags: docker, user-interface, centos

I have successfully been able to create a docker image with a matlab compiler runtime engine installed with centos6.9 as parent image. This works wonderfully and enables running matlab scripts within the container.

However, we also have a MATLAB GUI application for linux which we would like to launch from within the container. I was successful in running the GUI by X11 forwaring on Windows 10 by using xming server.

Question is: Is it possible to create a docker image for centos 6.9 with GUI capabilities(linux desktop) so that the X11 forwarding is not required? If yes, please point to some resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible by sharing X11 socket:

```
docker run -ti --rm \
       -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
       -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
       MATLAB
```

shamelessly copied from [here](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/)

**update**: for windows follow [this](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde)